# Spring JPA - transactional stored procedure for get-and-increment

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a MySQL stored procedure that:

1. reads the numeric value of a (non-PK) column named `current_tag_id`
2. increments the column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_AND_INCREMENT(IN table_id BIGINT, out tag BIGINT)
BEGIN
    select current_tag_id INTO tag from my_table where id = table_id;
    update my_table set current_tag_id = current_tag_id + 1 where id = table_id;
END
```

Since I want this operation to be **atomic**, I have to wrap it into a transaction for my Spring Boot application.

My question is: should I wrap the MySQL stored procedure in a MySQL transaction (with `BEGIN/COMMIT`) or should I go with calling the stored procedure with Spring JPA in an `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` annotated method?